# How to disable the Jetty DefaultHandler using XML (to prevent directory listings and webapp context listings)

Tags: jetty

I have a `JETTY_HOME` directory containing the unpacked Jetty distribution.

I want to disable the `DefaultHandler`, to achieve three things:

1. Prevent directory listings which would otherwise be controlled by the `dirAllowed` init parameter (the `DefaultServlet` is configured by this parameter).
2. Prevent web app context listings, which may reveal sensitive information such as server directory paths or other web app contexts running within the same Jetty instance.
3. Be sure that `DefaultHandler` doesn't provide access to any sensitive files in the event that I botch a web app deployment. I'm happy to implement my own static file serving servlet where necessary as an alternative to using `DefaultHandler`.

I could simply edit `JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.xml` and remove the `DefaultHandler` from there. However, `JETTY_HOME` is supposed to be read-only, and I'm only supposed to make changes in my `JETTY_BASE` folder. Only modifying `JETTY_BASE` comes with the advantage of not having to repeatedly modify `JETTY_HOME` when upgrading to a newer release of Jetty.

How to I make this change from inside `JETTY_BASE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DefaultHandler` is necessary, don't remove it.

Lets address each point.

---

> 1. Prevent directory listings which would otherwise be controlled by the `dirAllowed` init parameter (the `DefaultHandler` is configured by this parameter).

The `DefaultHandler` doesn't do directory listings.
That's the role of the `DefaultServlet` in a `WebAppContext`, or a `ResourceService` / `ResourceHandler` in an embedded scenario.

If you want to prevent directory listings presented by the `DefaultServlet` in a `WebAppContext` you need to configure the `DefaultServlet`.

You can do that with one of the following choices.

1. Declare the `<servlet>` entries in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` to configure the named servlet `default` to have a init-param of `dirAllowed` set to `false`.
   This is a change in the individual webapp's own `WEB-INF/web.xml`
2. Declare a servlet context init-parameter (not servlet specific, whole context), where the key `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed` is set to value `false`.
   This is a change in either the individual webapp's own `WEB-INF/web.xml` or the XML deployable (ie: `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml`) for each webapp.
3. Provide an alternate `webdefault.xml` for the defaultDescriptor that configures the default behavior to be dirAllowed=false.
   This is a change to the either the individual webapp XML deployable to set the `WebAppContext.setDefaultDescriptor()`, or the overall deployable defaults for the chosen `DeploymentManager` / `AppProvider` combo you are using.  This will also require a custom `${jetty.base}/etc/<name>.xml` which is your new default descriptor.
4. Provide a override descriptor xml that can be applied after your defaultDescriptor + webapp descriptor to configure dirAllowed=false.
   This is a change to the either the individual webapp XML deployable to set the `WebAppContext.setOverrideDescriptor()`, or the overall deployable defaults for the chosen `DeploymentManager` / `AppProvider` combo you are using.  This will also require a custom `${jetty.base}/etc/<name>.xml` which is your new override descriptor.

If you are using `ResourceService` / `ResourceHandler` in an embedded-jetty scenario, you can just call `ResourceService.setDirAllowed(false)`.

---

> 2. Prevent web app context listings, which may reveal sensitive information such as server directory paths or other web app contexts running within the same Jetty instance.

That's controlled by the `showContexts` configuration on the `DefaultHandler`.

There's 2 ways to control this behavior.

**Option A:** configure the `DefaultHandler`

You can add 2 files to your `${jetty.base}`

New file: `etc/tweak-defaulthandler.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">
<Configure id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
  <Set name="showContexts">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

Add a line to `${jetty.base}/start.d/tweaks.ini` to use this XML

```sh
$ cat start.d/tweaks.ini 
etc/tweak-defaulthandler.xml
```

**Option B:** just declare a ROOT context with default behavior for ROOT.

Create a `${jetty.base}/webapps/ROOT` directory.
Add a `${jetty.base}/webapps/ROOT/index.html` with whatever content you want.
That will be served instead of `DefaultHandler` creating the list of contexts.

---

> 3. Be sure that `DefaultHandler` doesn't provide access to any sensitive files in the event that I botch a web app deployment. I'm happy to implement my own static file serving servlet where necessary as an alternative to using `DefaultHandler`.

The `DefaultHandler` only serves 3 things.

1. `/favicon.ico` requests (only if a GET request)
2. `/` (show context listing) (only if a GET request and `showContexts` is true)
3. 404 Errors - all other requests that reach this handler.

You are confusing `DefaultServlet` / `ResourceService` / `ResourceHandler` with `DefaultHandler` a totally different thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough response. I've had a situation before when a web app deployment broke half-way, allowing the public to directory-browse through the mangled attempt at deployment. None of the options above achieve both 1) disable directory browsing when no properly deployed webapp exists (and therefore there was not an opportunity for a web.xml to specify a <context-param> for "dirAllowed") and 2) does not require modification to files in JETTY_HOME (such as changing dirAllowed in JETTY_HOME/etc/webdefault.xml). Please could you clarify if there is an angle I'm missing?

Comment: btw: typo in your XML: showContext -> showContexts

Comment: you don't have to edit anything in JETTY_HOME, there's nothing about my answer that indicates a change in JETTY_HOME, all of the work is entirely in JETTY_BASE.  Directory browsing is not something that exists outside of a webapp, if the webapp didn't deploy, there's no directory browsing.  the list of contexts is not directory browsing.

Comment: what I mean is: if a deployment script breaks and for any reason web.xml is not present, but other files from the package do get deployed into e.g. the ROOT webapp, then jetty will simply let someone browse through all of the files in the half-deployed web app because it does not see a web.xml file.

Comment: I added more detail to the options.

Comment: If you have even the slight chance of a failed exploded webapp directory deployments, then you shouldn't do a live deployment directly into `${jetty.base}/webapps/`, put them somewhere else, and use the standard XML deployable in `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml` referencing this other location only when you have confirmed everything is in place and sane first.

Comment: Also, failed deployments, for any reason, will mark the webapp as UNAVAILABLE, you literally cannot access the contents of that webapp in that state, all requests to that webapp will result in 503.

Comment: "Also, failed deployments, for any reason, will mark the webapp as UNAVAILABLE" => I've just tested this. If the deployment copied the entire web app to webapps/ROOT/ as normal, but simply forgot to include the web.xml file, then nearly the entire ROOT/ directory tree is browsable. This could happen e.g. if a deployment script forgot to include "*.xml" files when packaging things up. Only if there is a web.xml present that causes a problem will it become "UNAVAILABLE". The exception to directory browsing, for some reason, is that the WEB-INF/ directory cannot be browsed and shows a 404 error.

Comment: I see what you're saying though - I can use your technique for placing things elsewhere and using a `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml` file. This solves the problem, because the web.xml equivalent can't be missing yet other files present, in a way that makes those other files browsable. I'll also use sanity checks to prevent the jetty instance from being publicly accessible prior to the sanity check. Thank you so much for your help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your example (a directory without a `WEB-INF/web.xml`) is not a failed deployment, it's a complete and valid deployment, just one without a descriptor. It's not even a `WebAppContext`, it's just static files, served via the `ResourceService` (your changes to `DefaultHandler` and `DefaultServlet` have *no* impact to this kind of deployment).   If you had a `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml` for that directory first, you can specify that it must be configured as a `WebAppContext` and never deploy as a static directory.